# Oracle query on String

Tags: sql, oracle-xe, ora-00904

I want to perform my query on a string in this format, xxxx/xxxx

where x is a number. when I perform it using the Oracle interface or my C# application I get this error:

```
ORA-00904: "xxxx/xxxx": invalid identifier
```

I performed this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "My Table" WHERE Field="xxxx/xxxx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single quotes aroung SQL character literals like xxxx/xxxx:

```
SELECT * FROM "My Table" WHERE Field='xxxx/xxxx'
```